# Null instance on manager class extending from singleton class

Tags: unity, c#

I have four classes:

- **class A**, which is abstract and partial extending from singleton **class C**.
- **class A1**, which is partial and extending from **class A** .
- **class B**,  extending from **class A**.
- **class C**, a singleton which has code to throw an exception if the instance is `null`, and otherwise uses `DoNotDestroyOnLoad()`.

In scene view, I add **class B** to the scene. It works, but throws a null instance exception for **class A**, as it's instance is not present in scene. I think this is because **class A** extends from a singleton class, and it has ability to throw exceptions when the instance is null. I can not add the **class A** to the scene because it is abstract.

What can I do to in order to add the **class A** component to the scene, or otherwise not to get this error?

Comment: Class 'A' and class 'A Manager' are separate classes, or the same class? Maybe you can draw a diagram or include some example code. And are A and A1 two halves of your partial class A?

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity, class A and class A1 are two halves

Comment: Don't make class A extend from class C if you don't want the error.

Comment: Note that I am reimplementing the [tag:c#] tag. This *is* a programming question (complete with an un-complete programming answer). The *language* tag is especially relevant.

Comment: @Gnemlock will you have the same behaviour in UnityScript?

Comment: @Gnemlock Well if the language is not relevant, why put the tag?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt, because (to repeat myself) the *answers* may differ.

Comment: The user is asking "how do I do this" in context of C#. That is why they used the tag, initially (if not, well just change the tags if they clarify. Same as we always do.. no biggie.)

Comment: I was not saying we should use the [tag:unityscript] tag, aswell. I was trying to point out that I can not make sense of your logic.

Answer (score -1):

Yes I had to do exception handling on every point throwing null exception. Done.!!

Comment: could you provide better detail?

Comment: Editing your question for grammar and such, it appears best if you simply provide the excerpt of where you do your exception handling.